# 'Grid' placed widget in 'place' placed widget - not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm struggling to correctly place widget in my tkinter app. I want to place button in toolbar grid, but somehow it's not visible there. Can you take a look at my code and image which explaining window structure?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import LEFT, RIGHT


class Window(tk.Tk):
"""
    wrapped root
"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.initial_display_width_ratio_percentage = 80
        self.initial_display_height_ratio_percentage = 80

        self.min_width = 800
        self.min_height = 600

        self.window_width = self.initial_display_width_ratio_percentage/100*self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.window_height = self.initial_display_height_ratio_percentage/100*self.winfo_screenheight()
    
    self._center_window_and_set_size()
    

def _center_window_and_set_size(self):
    x = (self.winfo_screenwidth()/2) - (self.window_width/2)
    y = (self.winfo_screenheight()/2) - (self.window_height/2)
    self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.window_width, self.window_height, x, y))
    self.minsize(self.min_width, self.min_height)


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.project_tab = ProjectTab(self)
        self.preview_tab = PreviewTab(self)
        self.project_tab.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
        self.preview_tab.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="both", expand=True)


class ProjectTab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self['bg'] = "yellow"
        self.toolbar = Toolbar(self)
        self.toolbar.place(anchor="n", relwidth=2, height=30)


class PreviewTab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self["bg"] = "green"


class Toolbar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rgb_background_color = (255, 0, 0)
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self["bg"]= _rgb_to_tk_color(self.rgb_background_color)
        self.file_button = FileButton(self)
        self.file_button.grid(column=0, row=0)

    

class FileButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rgb_background_color = (0, 0, 255)
        self["bg"]= _rgb_to_tk_color(self.rgb_background_color)
        self["text"]= "File"



if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = Window()
    MainApplication(window).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    window.mainloop()
```

When I place the button in the project tab instead of toolbar, button is visible, and whats more - its visible ON the toolbar.
Any ideas? I bet I have wrong geometry management understanding.

Project structure pic:

[image: Project structure pic]

Comment: Are you aware that `relwidth=2` requests that the toolbar is twice as wide as the window? That's probably not _the_ problem, but it's _a_ problem.

Comment: As posted, this code won't run for a couple of different reasons: broken indentation and missing functions.

Comment: Yes, it's broken, but it's just the problem of pasting the code ;) relwidth was the real problem! thank you man! I will write down solution below :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so apparently, as Bryan noticed, I made a mistake by setting incorrect relwidth for the toolbar. I modified just one line!

```
self.toolbar.place(anchor="nw", relwidth=1, height=30)
```

Now everything works as a charm!